# behaviour and busy indicator

Tags: java, wicket

I have such things in my Java code:

```
//...omitted some not revelant code
AjaxIndicatorAppender indicator = new AjaxIndicatorAppender();
final RequiredTextField<String> nickField = new RequiredTextField<String>( "nick", new PropertyModel<String>( this, "nickValue" ) );
formContainer.add( nickField );
indicator.bind(nickField);
nickField.add( new MyValidatingBehaviour( (Form) formContainer, "onkeyup", Duration.ONE_SECOND, indicator ) );

//...

private class MyValidatingBehaviour extends AjaxFormValidatingBehavior implements IAjaxIndicatorAware
{
    AjaxIndicatorAppender indicator;

    private MyValidatingBehaviour( Form<?> form, String event, final Duration throttleDelay, AjaxIndicatorAppender indicator )
    {
        super( form, event );
        this.setThrottleDelay( throttleDelay );
        this.indicator = indicator;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAjaxIndicatorMarkupId()
    {
        return indicator.getMarkupId();
    }
}
```

But nothing happens, there's no any indicator, am I doing something wrong? Couldnt find any example for my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
indicator.bind(nickField);
```

it should be

```
nickField.add(indicator);
```

And it works :)